# My code is freezing and using to much CPU power. (Python)

Tags: python, cpu-usage

I am attempting to make a sort of AI like script which will figure out your phrase. It is still a work in progress and is not yet complete.
Each guess should print the following info:
The text produced: ......... The string generated by the script.
The length of the text: ... The length of the previously mentioned string.
The score of the text: ..... The script will score the text based on how long it is and what letters are in it.
The target text: ................. The text it is trying to produce.
For some reason, after the first string the code freezes. I am hoping anyone can help, Thanks in advance!

```
import random

posAlpha = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h",
            "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p",
            "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x",
            "y", "z", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F",
            "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N",
            "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V",
            "W", "X", "Y", "Z", "!", "?", ",", ".",
            " ", "&", "0", "1", "2", "3",
            "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"]

def scoreText(input, goal):
    output = 0-abs(len(input)-len(goal))
    for i in range(len(min(input, goal, key=len))):
        if not (input[i] in goal):
            output+=0
        elif not (input[i] == goal[i]):
            output += 1
        else:
            output += 2
    if output < 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return output

goal = input("Target phrase: ")
score = 0
Ai=""
for i in range(random.randrange(round(len(goal)*0.5), len(goal)*2)):
    Ai = Ai+ random.choice(posAlpha)

score = scoreText(Ai, goal)
print("Result:        " + Ai)
print("Result Length: " + str(len(Ai)))
print("Goal:          " + goal)
print("Score:         " + str(score))
print()

while True:
    oldAi = Ai
    Ai = ""
    for i in range(len(Ai)-1):
        if (score == 1 or random.randrange(1, score) == 1):
            Ai = Ai+random.choice(posAlpha)
        else:
            Ai = Ai+oldAi[i]
    while True:
        lenVariation=random.randrange(-4, 4)
        if not (len(Ai)+lenVariation > len(goal)*2 or len(Ai)+lenVariation<round(len(goal)*0.5)):
            if lenVariation > 0:
                for i in range(lenVariation):
                    Ai = Ai+ random.choice(posAlpha)
                    break
            elif lenVariation < 0:
                for i in range(lenVariation):
                    AI=Ai[:-1]
                    break
    score = scoreText(Ai, goal)
    print("Result:        " + Ai)
    print("Result Length: " + str(len(Ai)))
    print("Goal:          " + goal)
    print("Score:         " + str(score))
    print()
input("Goal Achived!!")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because the execution is stuck in the second infinite loop. The condition `(len(Ai)+lenVariation > len(goal)*2 or len(Ai)+lenVariation<round(len(goal)*0.5))` is met every time after the first execution so the if statement is never evaluated to `True` and the while loop is never exited.

Also, note that your `break` statements only exist the for loop and not the while loop so statements after the second break are never executed.

Comment: Thanks! I'll look into that! 